# Desarrumação na grid do bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Olá, boa tarde, teria alguma maneira de fixar os col-md aonde foi posicionado sem que haja alteração?

Antigamente eu fazia deste modo:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Porém agora eu preciso que seja deste modo:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Pois a aparição dos produtos é automática e não tem como adicionar uma nova col-md-12 pra delimitar o espaço.

Gostaria que ficasse tudo certo assim: http://prntscr.com/l1e8ql

Porém basta ter um desnível de tamanho nos box ou realizar o fechamento de um que sai do lugar: http://prntscr.com/l1e8z4

Isso vale para as perguntas do faq também: http://prntscr.com/l1e92q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo pelo que entendi da sua resposta parece que é isso que vc precisa. Porém no seu projeto deve ter algo a mais que está fazendo quebrar o grid original do Bootstrap, pq mesmo com um `col` dentro da outra, sem `row` o exemplo abaixo não apresento o mesmo problema que o seu.

Execute em "Página toda" para ver a responsividade:

```css
[class^="col-"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

 
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-4">
   Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic rerum quia, necessitatibus repellendus perspiciatis reprehenderit veniam asperiores harum totam labore dolore corrupti voluptatibus molestiae culpa numquam at ipsam tenetur aliquid.
  </div>
   
  <div class="col-md-4">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, atque.
   <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
  </div>
   
  <div class="col-md-4">
   Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic rerum quia, necessitatibus repellendus perspiciatis reprehenderit veniam asperiores harum totam labore dolore corrupti voluptatibus molestiae culpa numquam at ipsam tenetur aliquid.
   <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
  </div>
   
  <div class="col-md-4">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, atque.
  </div>
   
  <div class="col-md-4">
   Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic rerum quia, necessitatibus repellendus perspiciatis reprehenderit veniam asperiores harum totam labore dolore corrupti voluptatibus molestiae culpa numquam at ipsam tenetur aliquid.
  </div>
   
  <div class="col-md-4">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, atque.
   <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
  </div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, atque.
  <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
```

---

Se vc quiser que todos os `col` tenha a altura do maior irmão vc da fileira vc pode usar `display:flex` no pai.

**Ficaria dessa forma:**

```css
.col-md-12 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
[class^="col-"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-4">
   Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic rerum quia, necessitatibus repellendus perspiciatis reprehenderit veniam asperiores harum totam labore dolore corrupti voluptatibus molestiae culpa numquam at ipsam tenetur aliquid.
  </div>
   
  <div class="col-md-4">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, atque.
   <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
  </div>
   
  <div class="col-md-4">
   Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic rerum quia, necessitatibus repellendus perspiciatis reprehenderit veniam asperiores harum totam labore dolore corrupti voluptatibus molestiae culpa numquam at ipsam tenetur aliquid.
   <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
  </div>
   
  <div class="col-md-4">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, atque.
  </div>
   
  <div class="col-md-4">
   Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic rerum quia, necessitatibus repellendus perspiciatis reprehenderit veniam asperiores harum totam labore dolore corrupti voluptatibus molestiae culpa numquam at ipsam tenetur aliquid.
  </div>
   
  <div class="col-md-4">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, atque.
   <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, atque.
   <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não deu certo! :( http://prntscr.com/l1wocw

Comment: @RonyOliveira Tentou colocando isso na div de fora que vai receber os conteúdos? `.col-md-12 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}` ?

Comment: Tentei novamente e deu certo, obrigado!!

Comment: @RonyOliveira que bom que deu certo. Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como aceita nesse ✔ ai ao lado esquerdo perto das setinhas. Basta clicar nele, assim a pergunta não fica aberta já tendo sido resolvida :)

Comment: pronto, marquei :)